# Pad selected lines to cursor position in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

In Visual Studio 2019, I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>(Arrow Keys)</kbd> to multi-line edit the "virtual" whitespace then press any key to make all the lines padded with space to the selected column, I use this a lot to make initialization code easier to read. However, when I switched to Visual Studio Code, I could not find the equivalent. The closest thing I was able to find was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>(Arrow Keys)</kbd>. This is not quite what I need since it only places each line cursor at the end instead of the "virtual" whitespace in the previous example.

Here's a visual example in Visual Studio 2019 (I don't know how to make GIFs):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there any equivalent in VSCode or am I stuck without it for now?

Comment: C & C++ are different languages :)  (Changed your tag)

Comment: See [Virtual Space is not implemented.] https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13960 . This has been an issue for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this fairly well with a macro.  Using a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) put this into your `settings.json`:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

  {
    "command": "multiCommand.padTrailingSpaces",
    "sequence": [
      "editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected",
       "cursorHomeSelect",
      {
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet,

                       // pad end of each line with lots of spaces's'
        "args": {
          "snippet": "$TM_SELECTED_TEXT                                              ",
        }
      },

      "cursorHomeSelect",
      {
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",  
        "args": {

          // keep first 30 characters, increase if you typically need more
          "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.{30}).*/$1/g}",  
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The above puts a cursor at the end of each line, adds way more spaces than you should ever need, and then keeps only the first 30 characters on each line.

Choose some keybinding (in keybindings.json):

```
{
  "key": "alt+s",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.padTrailingSpaces" },
  "when": "editorTextFocus" 
},
```

[image: macro to pad spaces to each line]

---

First select all the lines you want padded, than trigger your keybinding.  Then al least you have all the cursors lined up with padding and it is easy to go left or right with all of them at once.

You probably can reduce the `30` that I use just for demonstration purposes by a some - depends on how long your longest line usually is.

Answer (score 8):

Good question, I couldn't find a way to do the same in VScode, but here's a little hack to get the same effect:

[image]

- Ctrl+Alt+(Arrow Keys) all of the lines
- End button
- Tab over, so the furthest cursor to the left is where you want it
- Escape
- Ctrl+Alt+(Arrow Keys) all of the lines again

Obviously it's not as nice of a work-flow.. but it works. You could also look into VScode extensions, to make this faster or make your own

Comment: @James I guess that is fixable by doing Shift + End followed by backspace