# How to paste a multiline selection as an aligned straight column after lines of varying length?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My source file looks like

```
123456789
456
789
```

and I want to paste the following text appending to the end of the each line

```
abcd
efgh
hijk
```

the desired output should be as follow (which can be done in ultraedit)

```
123456789 abcd  
456       efgh  
789       hijk
```

but with vscode I can only get

```
123456789   abcd
456   efgh
789   hijk
```

Can anyone can show me how?

Answer (score 0):

Using my answer from [Pad selected lines to cursor position in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59793465/pad-selected-lines-to-cursor-position-in-vscode/59794113#59794113]) but using a smaller number, like 10.

from within the macro at the link modify the following line:

```
      // keep first 10 characters, increase/decrease to suit your needs but always overshoot
      "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.{10}).*/$1/g}",
```

The idea is to include more spaces than you are likely to need and then keep only the first 10 characters - so your values + enough spaces to equal 10 total characters.  Depending on your likely values, choose a sufficiently higher number to get your column of cursors beyond where you will likely want them to end up - it is easy to move them left/right as a straight group afterwards if need be.

[And make sure the setting `Multi Cursor Paste` is set to its default option `spread`.]

[image: pad and paste demo]

In the demo the macro keybinding <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> doesn't show up for some reason but that is all I used to get the column of cursors aligned to the right of your values between the copy and paste.