# Aligning Multiline Edit Cursors With Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, multiline

With Visual Studio Code's multiline edit functionality, is there a way to easily align all cursors in a column at the end of a line if the whitespace doesn't already exist (similar to what is possible with Notepad++)?

From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Comment: as far as I know the multi cursors can only be set where a single cursor could be. go to the end of the line(s), add a bunch of spaces, go to the begin of line and move the cursors to the required location, select to end of line and delete

Comment: There is no built-in way to do what you want.  But see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59793465/pad-selected-lines-to-cursor-position-in-vscode/59794113#59794113 for a pretty easy workaround.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you rioV8 and Mark. Those are both helpful suggestions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is this extension by Mike Moore

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yo1dog.cursor-align

First I install the above extension.

```
Test Test               <- Space here
even longer test text
testing
```

Selected multiple cursor as shown by `|`

```
Test Test               |
even longer test text|
testing|
```

Then in command pallet (`ctrl`+`p`) and (`shift`+`>`) I type `Align Cusor`. Else I use  `Alt`+`A`. Giving you this desired result

```
Test Test               |
even longer test text   |
testing                 |
```